# What is the correct way of getting an app key in google?

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm trying out a simple code I found using www::google::customsearch. I know that google and yahoo has already change its policy in allowing these searches.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use WWW::Google::CustomSearch;

my $api_key = 'Your_API_Key';
my $cx      = 'Search_Engine_Identifier';
my $engine  = WWW::Google::CustomSearch->new(api_key => $api_key, cx => $cx);
print Dumper($engine->search("Google"));
```

I am not sure if this module will work. I was just trying to test it. This is a sample from cpan. I tried running the code I keep getting a missing argument which is the api key.

This is so far what I have done. I have signed in google and created a custom search engine. I copied the search engine reference code. I have tried the example code in javascript. I placed it in a sample html. It works.

I have also signed in google and turned on custom search engine api, and generated an app key.

What is the correct step in getting an application key?

Answer (score 3):

> I tried running the code I keep getting a missing argument which is the api key.

You did not try to execute the given code as it is, did you? You are supposed to pass the actual key in below line.

```
my $api_key = 'Your_API_Key';
```

`Your_API_Key` should be replaced with the key you get from Google API console.

> What is the correct step in getting an application key?

Quoting from the documentation on how to find it.

> The JSON / Atom Custom Search API requires the use of an API key,
>   which you can get from the Google APIs console. The API provides 100
>   search queries per day for free. If you need more, you may sign up for
>   billing in the console.
>
> The official Google API document can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview). For more
>   information about the Google custom search, please click [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list).

Comment: I did replace $api_key with the api key I got from google. For security purposes I couldn't really display it since I'm hoping there was only a delay in the approval. Its says it takes 5 minutes after generating the key. Who knows maybe mine got delayed. The site did advice that keep it secure cause if it got leaked I might have bandwidth consumption issues

Comment: Tried it a few times it seems its still api key. I think I need I lack something or made a mistake somewhere, I don't think I need OAuth2.0 since according to the google document if OAuth2.0 is needed if it needs to get user data. I'm suspecting it needs me to get a web hosting and a real app site.